# Simplifying Rational Expressions and Proving Trivial Rational Equivalences in Coq

Tags: coq

Which tactics can I use to perform simplifications of rational expressions and prove trivial rational equivalences as shown in the following example?

```
Require Import Coq.QArith.QArith.
Open Scope Q_scope.

Lemma Example : (0 + 0) / 1 == 0.
```

Comment: Here, `reflexivity` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about rational in Coq, but if their implementation is constructive, you'll be able to simplify such expressions using `simpl` (you might need to first `unfold` some definitions) or `compute`. Since `reflexivity` is done modulo conversion, it should also solve such goals.

However, you might have trouble simplifying expression with free variable (for example that

```
 forall q:Q, (q + 0) / 1 = q.
```

Maybe there's a tactic like `omega` dedicated to this task. You could maybe try with `ring` or `lia`.